# Can't delete comment from google chrome under linux

Tags: bug, status-declined, google-chrome

I have found that I can't delete comments with google chrome under linux.

My Chrome version is: 16.0912:41 beta.

Basically, when clicking the x next to the comment it doesn't seem to remove the comment even after a refresh.

I logged in using firefox and was able to remove the comment right away.

Comment: As Sathya has said, we don't investigate beta versions of browsers.  I hope it's not a problem in the next stable release :)

Answer (score 2):

Beta versions of browsers aren't supported - and yes this bug has been around for at least a month in the beta version, but works fine stable version.

I suggest you try the stable version of Chrome

Comment: btw, the same "bug" affects Vote to Delete as well.

Comment: Very odd, it works in the dev version of chrome...